# IOS 15 Library not working in sandbox environment and breaking access to App Store after use .Also getting empty array RNIap.requestSubscription()

Tags: in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit, ios15

Version of react-native-iap 7.0.5
Version of react-native 0.63.4
Platforms you faced the error (IOS or Android or both?)
IOS 15

Expected behavior
Be able to make inapp purchases

Actual behavior
In sandbox environment it breaks StoreKit

Tested environment (Emulator? Real Device?)
Real Device (iPhone XR, 12)

```
await RNIap.initConnection().then(async(output) =>{
          console.log(output)
          await RNIap.getSubscriptions(ENV.ENV.subsItems)
         .then(async(subscriptions) => {
             console.log(subscriptions)
             if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
                 await RNIap.clearTransactionIOS();
               }
               await RNIap.requestSubscription(sku,false).catch(err => { console.log(err.code, err.message); });

         }).catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```